# Compile Latex document by python

Tags: python, latex

I have been struggling with compiling latex document and creating pdf.

I have successfully created .tex file by python. I want to make it even more automated by compiling .tex in python.

The code I have tried is:

```
import os 
os.system("filename.tex")
```

I put this codes at the end of my python code.

But it only opens the software Texmaker, not compiling it to pdf.

If you could give me any hint I will be so grateful!!

Comment: You'll need to run the [`pdflatex` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21405/how-to-create-pdf-with-command-line-using-miktex) as `os.system('pdflatex filename.tex')` Alternatively use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thank you Mitchell! Thanks for the quick reply again! Both you and Izaaks' methods are correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually run some kind of command that makes the pdf. In my case I
might use `pdflatex`, although you should know that compiling LaTeX isn't always
as easy as running latex once.

```
import subprocess

with open("filename.tex", "w") as tex_file:
    tex_file.write(r"""
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
""")

subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "filename.tex"])
```